# 'I think' In Relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> Put your clock forward to the furthest it can go **which I think is** 2025.

**which** relative pronoun is used for 'furthest' and acting as a subject for 'is 2025'.

My question is that it's also working as a object for 'I think' at the same time. Or, 'I think' is not a part of relative clause.?

And can it be rewritten as:

> **a.** Put your clock forward to the furthest it can go Which is 2025, I think?

> **b.** Put your clock forward to the furthest it can go which I think that is 2025?

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question. Asking more than one is off-topic. I've edited out your second question. If you really want to ask it, open a new question

Comment: In a. the relative clause is "which is 2025", In b. the relative clause is "which I think is 2025". Btw,, drop the "that"; it is not needed.

Comment: @BillJ in original sentence, one of my question is how 'I think' connects with 'which'  as which is already a subject for 'is 2025'. 'I think' seems like a different clause as It does not seem to be connected in the relative clause by which.

Comment: There is no object in any of your examples. In the original, the relative clause is "which I think is 2025". Within the relative clause is an embedded content clause, "is 2025", whose subject is "which". Is that clear now?

Comment: @BillJ As you just said that the embedded content clause 'is 2025' has which, relative pronoun, as a subject. But 'which' also came before 'I think' so there must be some relation between these two.

Comment: And In your first comment you said that in 'a.' only 'which is 2025' is a relative clause which I understand too. I just wanted to know that the 'I think' part which is separated by a comma at the end of the sentence is an 'adjunct' or called something different?

Comment: Yes, "which" came before "I think", but there is **no** syntactic relationship. In your original example, "Which" is called a 'prenucleus'. In a. "I think" is a supplementary adjunct. not part of the clause.

Comment: @BillJ Thankyou now I have understood. It took me many attempts to make my question clear. I should've asked like this in the original question. My whole question was if there was any relation between those two or not. Again thanks. And If you could just write it as an answer so that I would mark tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] *Put your clock forward to the furthest it can go, which I think* [ ___ *is*
> *2025*].
>
> [2] *Put your clock forward to the furthest it can go, which is 2025,* [*I*
> *think*].

Preliminary point. There is no object in the relative clause in either [1] or [2].

In [1] the relative clause is "which I think is 2025". Within the relative clause is the bracketed content clause, which has a gap '___' in the position of subject, and this gap is linked to "which" in prenuclear position. In other words, the relativised element is not object of "think" in the relative clause, but subject
of the content clause embedded within it.

In [2] the relative clause is "which is 2025". The clause "I think" is not part of the main or relative clause but is a supplementary adjunct. The relativised element, "which", is subject of the relative clause.

In both examples, the relative clause is of the supplementary (non-defining) kind, whose antecedent is the expression "the furthest it can go".

Comment: And If I say 'Put your clock forward to the furthest it can go which I think to be 2025' then 'which' become the object of the 'think' and 'to be 2025'  an objective complement?

Comment: @RADS No: it's not a natural way of saying it, but it has the same analysis as [1] in my answer, i.e. "which" is subject in the embedded clause "to be 2025".

Answer (score 2):

The object that's being modified includes more than you stated (and the sentence needs a comma):

> Put your clock forward to the furthest it can go, which I think is 2025.

What's being modified is **the furthest it can go**. The comma indicates that the secondary phrase is not required. It adds clarity, but the sentence is fine with or without it.

Correct versions of your other examples:

> (a) Put your clock forward to the furthest it can go, which is 2025, I think.
>
> (b) Put your clock forward to the furthest it can go, which I think is 2025.

Comment: The convention rules require a comma after **2025** in item (a).

Comment: Thank you, I added it.

Answer (score 2):

It can be written both ways. The reason has nothing to do with relative clauses, so let's just treat the relative clause part of the sentence as an independent sentence, which looks like this in the original structure:

> a. I think the furthest it can go is 2025.

When using "think" to introduce a particular thought, it can come at the end of the sentence, so our example can be rewritten like this with the same meaning:

> b. The furthest it can go is 2025, I think.

You can use either of these versions as a relative clause in your example sentence. Again, there's nothing special here about relative clauses, just the grammar of the verb "think".

Comment: If I say, 'Put your clock forward to the furthest it can go, which I think to be 2025.' Here it seems 'I think' with 'which' become relative clause.

Comment: And one of my question was how 'I think' connects with the relative clause In original sentence. As 'which' in og sentence came for 'which is 2025' acting as a subject. So how it(I think) connects with the sentence

Comment: @RADS The relative clause is "*which I think is 2025*". So, "I think" doesn't "connect with the relative clause" because it is part of the relative clause. Within the relative clause, "I think" introduces "the furthest it can go is 2025" and has no other grammatical role in the rest of the sentence.